# FullCalendar: receive error while trying to display events using json file

Tags: javascript, php, json, fullcalendar

Following is my JSON file:

> ```
> <?php
>               $driver_booking = q("select * from vehicle_driver_booking where vehicle_id = ".$_REQUEST['ch']);
>               $array = array();
>               foreach($driver_booking as $bookings) {
>                   $driver = getRow("vehicle_driver", $bookings['driver_id']);
>                   //return date_time from only....
>                   $date_from = date("Y-m-d",$bookings['datetime_from']);
>                   $time_from = date("H:i:s",$bookings['datetime_from']);
>                   //return date_time to only.....
>                   $date_to = date("Y-m-d",$bookings['datetime_to']);
>                   $time_to = date("H:i:s",$bookings['datetime_to']);
>                   if($bookings['days_option'] == 1) {
>                       $start = $date_from."T".$time_from;
>                       $array[] = array('id' => $bookings['id'], 'title' => $driver['name'], 'start' => $start, 'allDay' => false);
>                   } else {
>                       $start = $date_from."T".$time_from;
>                       $end = $date_to."T".$time_to;
>                       $array[] = array('id' => $bookings['id'], 'title' => $driver['name'], 'start' => $start, 'end' => $end, 'allDay' => false);
>                   }
>
>               }
>
>               echo json_encode($array);
>           ?>
> ```

Following is part of the calendar where I am trying to get json data from above file.

```
eventSources: [

    // your event source
    {
        url: '/vehicle_json.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
           // custom_param1: 'something',
            //custom_param2: 'somethingelse'
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
        },
        color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
        textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
    }

    // any other sources...

],
```

or I tried with this following way as well...but not worked and above give me alert message and following give me nothing at all.

```
events: 'vehicle_json.php',
```

& once if above issue will resolve then I also wanted to update my events through using following where when the record save it refresh the events to show the update ones.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "save_booking_details.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {booking_id: bookingid, date_single: datesingle, date_from: datefrom, date_to: dateto},
    success: function(data){
        //alert(data);
        //location.reload();

        //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', curSource[0]);
    //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', curSource[0]);
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    //Calendar.init();
            //setTimeout(function(){ Calendar.init(); }, 10000);

    }, error: function() {
        alert("something went wrong!");
    }
});
```

So can someone please help as I am looking for solution since yesterday thank you guys in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide a parameter called `ch`. Not sure what it is

```
data: {
    'ch': "something I don't know"
},
```

Comment: Sorry bro but not work at all:  data: {
    ch: 'bla'
               // custom_param1: 'something',
                //custom_param2: 'somethingelse'
            },

Comment: Are you sure your `vehicle_id` has something like 'bla' in your database? What's the new error?

Comment: Wow bro thank you its' worked as I was doing for so long that I didn't think about it however do you have a solution for my other issue which I mentioned above regarding $('#calendar').fullcalendar('refetchEvent')